# Merge two data.tables, add another column and keep the duplicates

Tags: merge, duplicates, data.table, match

I have two data.tables:

Df1: (15.000 observations)

| NO | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 10101 | 8119500101 |
| 10601 | 13071516106 |
| 10601 | 13071516106 |
| 10800 | 8235500200 |

Df2:(45.000.000 observations)

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| 8119500101 | 13071516106 |
| 8235500200 | 8235500200 |
| 8119500101 | 8119500101 |

Columns "ID" and "from" and "to" contain the same values. I would like to match each "ID" and "from and "ID" and "to" to add the colum "NO":

Df2:

| from | to | NO_from | NO_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8119500101 | 13071516106 | 10101 | 10601 |
| 8235500200 | 8235500200 | 10800 | 10800 |
| 8119500101 | 8119500101 | 10101 | 10101 |

Also, for some of the "NO" values there are no matches, however, instead of ignoring them, I want to keep them, as well as duplicates.:

Df2:

| from | to | NO_from | NO_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8119500101 | 13071516106 | 10101 | 10601 |
| 8235500200 | 8235500200 | 10800 | 10800 |
| 8119500101 | 8119500101 | 10101 | 10101 |
| NA | NA | 00008 | 00008 |

I tried this, however it did not work:

```r
setDT(df2) [, "from_NO" := df1$NO[match(df2$from, df1$ID)],]
setDT(df2) [, "to_NO" := df1$NO[match(df2$to, df1$ID)],]
```

Also, I got the following error:

> Supplied 44571901 items to be assigned to 15782 items of column 'from_MT_Zone'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

What can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-step join:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(Df1)
setDT(Df2)
Df2[Df1, NO_from := i.NO, on = .(from == ID)
  ][Df1, NO_to := i.NO, on = .(to == ID)][]
#          from          to NO_from NO_to
#         <num>       <num>   <int> <int>
# 1: 8119500101 13071516106   10101 10601
# 2: 8235500200  8235500200   10800 10800
# 3: 8119500101  8119500101   10101 10101
```

For your second step, I'll modify `Df1` to include a row that is not mapped in `Df2`.

```r
Df1 <- rbindlist(list(Df1, data.table(NO=10999L, ID=10)))
Df1
#       NO          ID
#    <int>       <num>
# 1: 10101  8119500101
# 2: 10601 13071516106
# 3: 10601 13071516106
# 4: 10800  8235500200
# 5: 10999          10

rbindlist(list(
  # the original, after our double-merge above
  Df2,
  # everything else
  Df1[(!NO %in% Df2$NO_from & !NO %in% Df2$NO_to),
      .(NO_from = NO, NO_to = NO)]
  ),fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
#          from          to NO_from NO_to
#         <num>       <num>   <int> <int>
# 1: 8119500101 13071516106   10101 10601
# 2: 8235500200  8235500200   10800 10800
# 3: 8119500101  8119500101   10101 10101
# 4:         NA          NA   10999 10999
```